# Allow Mod-Security for request uri

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

```
I am trying to add exemption for Mod-security rule  in REQUEST-900-before file for the following request :- 
`1668035916.075452 [00] [client 127.0.0.1] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "(?i:(?:[\"'`](?:;?\\s*?(?:having|select|union)\\b\\s*?[^\\s]|\\s*?!\\s*?[\"'`\\w])|(?:c(?:onnection_id|urrent_user)|database)\\s*?\\([^\\)]*?|u(?:nion(?:[\\w(\\s]*?select| select @)|ser\\s*?\\([^\\)]*?)|s(?:chema\\s*?\\([^\\)]*?|elect.*?\\w?user\\()|in ..." at ARGS:queryEditor. [file "/etc/modsecurity/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "183"] [id "942190"] [msg "Detects MSSQL code execution and information gathering attempts"] [data "Matched Data: \x22SELECT . found within ARGS:queryEditor: {\x22title\x22:\x22Untitled Query 1\x22,\x22dbId\x22:null,\x22schema\x22:null,\x22autorun\x22:false,\x22sql\x22:\x22SELECT ...\x22,\x22queryLimit\x22:1000}"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/66"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [hostname "a938b1191f37"] [uri "http://iq.haproxy.xyz/tabstateview/"] [unique_id "0A000806:E240_AC110002:01BB_636C354C_0033:0024"]`
```

Is there any-way of just saying to Mod-security allow this request

```
I have tried this : -
`SecRule REQUEST_URI "^http://iq\.haproxy\.xyz/tabstateview/$" \
    "id:1000,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942190;ARGS:queryEditor"`
```

Not able to make it work

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_URI does NOT contain a domain name, see:
https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#request_uri

If you want an exclusion rule that si tied also to the domain name, i suggest this rule:

```
SecRule SERVER_NAME "@streq iq.haproxy.xyz" \
    "id:1000,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@streq /tabstateview/" \
        "t:none,\
        ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942190;ARGS:queryEditor"
```

Comment: Hi @azurit I tried the rule you sent and it seems it didn't work in this case. 

SecRule SERVER_NAME "@streq iq.haproxy.xyz" \
    "id:1000,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@streq /tabstateview/" \
        "t:none,\
        ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942190;ARGS:queryEditor"

I have tried this with phase 2 as well. Just to confirm this will go in REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf right? Thank you for answering my question

Comment: Yes, it goes into REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf. Can you look into error log and see if there's something new?

Comment: I managed it by using below rule in test enviornment
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "^(iq|data)\.haproxy\.xyz$" \
    "id:1000,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    log,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /tabstateview" \
        "t:none,\
        ctl:ruleRemoveById=942190"